# Android: trying to add a fragment to the backstack ("Blank activity" project)

Tags: android

I have just created a new "Blank activity" project. And now I would like to add a fragment to the backstack when pressing the button that the "Blank activity" shows. The problem: the applicaction closes unexpectedly when pressing the button.

[Steps I have followed to create a fragment from an activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html)

[Steps I have followed to add a fragment to the backstack](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

These are the only codes I added to the Blank Activity project:

//MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ExampleFragment ef = new ExampleFragment();

            /////// This line closes the application /////////
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(65, ef)  //65 is random number
                     // Add this transaction to the back stack
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        }
    });

}
```

This is the layout of the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.tirengarfio.myapplication.ExampleFragment"
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

ExampleFragment.java

```
package com.example.tirengarfio.myapplication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First understand difference between 
1. Adding a fragment statically vs
2. Adding a fragment dynamically.

This tutorial will help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html
( check section 5.1 and section 5.2 in the tutorial )

Also you are doing

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(65, ef)  //65 is random number
                     // Add this transaction to the back stack
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

verify the .add(65, ef) part. You cannot add a random int 65 it has to be resource id for the container view where you want do dynamically add a fragment.